# Multiple Boolean operations like (l and r ) ==None:

Tags: python

I am working on tree problem [Symmetric Tree - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/symmetric-tree/)

> Given a binary tree, check whether it is a mirror of itself (ie, symmetric around its center).
>
> For example, this binary tree `[1,2,2,3,4,4,3]` is symmetric:
>
> ```
>     1
>    / \
>   2   2
>  / \ / \
> 3  4 4  3
> ```
>
> But the following `[1,2,2,null,3,null,3]` is not:
>
> ```
>    1
>   / \
>  2   2
>   \   \
>    3    3
> ```
>
> **Note:**
>   Bonus points if you could solve it both recursively and iteratively.

Read the following solution

```
class Solution(object):
    def isSymmetric(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: bool
        """

        def isSym(l,r):
            if l==None and r==None:
                return True
            elif (l and r ) ==None:
                return False
            if l.val == r.val:
                return isSym(l.left,r.right) and isSym(l.right,r.left)
            else:
                return False

        if not root:
            return True
        if root:
            return isSym(root.left,root.right)
```

I  am aware that `elif (l and r ) ==None:` is `l == None  or r == Nne`, but this expression is anti-intuitive

```
In [5]: (3 or 4) == 4                                                                                                         
Out[5]: False

In [6]: (3 and 4) == 4                                                                                                        
Out[6]: True
```

How to interpret it intuitively, is it a trick play on precedence?

Comment: `print( 3 or 4 )`, `print( 4 or 3 )`, `print( 3 and 4 )`, `print( 4 and 3 )`

Comment: lol, interesting, thank you. @furas

Comment: (x and y) Returns x if x is False, y otherwise
(x or y) Returns y if x is False, x otherwise

Comment: you will see that `and` gives you second value, `or` gives first value. But try to use 0 (zero) which is treated similar to None or False or empty list and you see different results.